# Python - Data frames merged (ignoring columns)

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, merge

I have a daily process that stores csv files on S3 lake. The process needs to run daily, but the data doesn't change that often. I want to push the files on S3 and into the data lake ONLY when something changes and only WHAT changes. Thus avoiding duplicates in spectrum and Redsfhit. How can I merge these two data frames ? I need to ignore the last 2 columns. Bellow is an example of the data frames.

```
df_yesteday=
    id  name    desc    extracted_date          processed_date
    1   apple   red     2020-04-15 12:56:28     2020-04-15 12:58:28
    2   pear    yellow  2020-04-15 12:56:28     2020-04-15 12:58:28
    3   banana  yellow  2020-04-15 12:56:28     2020-04-15 12:58:28

df_today=
    id  name    desc    extracted_date          processed_date
    1   apple   green   2020-04-16 12:56:13     2020-04-16 12:58:13
    2   pear    yellow  2020-04-16 12:56:13     2020-04-16 12:58:13
    3   banana  yellow  2020-04-16 12:56:13     2020-04-16 12:58:13

df_merged=
    id  name    desc    extracted_date          processed_date
    1   apple   green   2020-04-16 12:56:13     2020-04-16 12:48:13
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks,
Rosa

Answer (score 0):

Not a join but iterating over the data frame if that is feasible:

```
df_merged = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in df_today.iterrows():
    if (row[0] != df_yesteday.loc[index,:][0]) or (row[1] != df_yesteday.loc[index,:][1]):
        df_merged = df_merged.append(df_today.loc[index,:])
```

This however assumes that the data frame indices are consistent i.e. no new indices appear inbetween from one day to another.

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional complication. There are 11 different files. So, I have a for loop iterating over one bucket, storing those 11 data frames in a dictionary. 
Then I have another for loop iterating over second bucket, finding the most recent files. Storing those 11 data frames in a dictionary.

```
df_collection = {}
df_collection2 = {}

for obj in SOURCE_BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix=SOURCE_BUCKET_PATH):
                if obj.key.endswith(currentdate.strftime("%Y%m%d") + ".csv"):  ##ends with the today's date.csv. Only
                                path = "s3://" + source_bucket + "/" + obj.key

                                x = obj.key.replace(SOURCE_BUCKET_PATH, "")
                                x = x.split("/")

                                # --- read into dataframe and add to df_collection--
                                df = pd.read_csv(path, index_col=False)
                                df.head()
                                df = df * 1  # turns true/false to 1/0

                                df_collection.update({x[1]: df})

for obj in TARGET_BUCKET.objects.filter(Prefix=TARGET_BUCKET_PATH):
                if obj.key.endswith(yesterday + ".csv"):  ##ends with the today's date.csv. Only
                                path_old = "s3://" + target_bucket + "/" + obj.key

                                df_old = pd.read_csv(path_old, index_col=False)
                                df_old.head()

                                df_collection2.update({x[1]: df_old})
```